# LaTex: how to add a line break in the titke

Tags: latex, xelatex

I have a poster to do but the tile was to long so I tried to break the title into two lines.

I tried:

```
\title{2D Bipedal Walking Simulation with \\ Deep Reinforcement Learning}
```

and I also tried

```
\title{2D Bipedal Walking Simulation with \protect\\ Deep Reinforcement Learning}
```

but somehow the compiler shows the same error:
[image]

and I don't know what's going wrong.

And also, I used XeLaTex to compile the tex file.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [TeX SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is a more appropriate venue for this question.

Comment: Can you provide a [complete, minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) of your setup so we can replicate your issue? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow the community to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly the same problem as yours.